# Can i use python to CSP?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, constraints

How can i make a Constraint Solver Programing (CSP) based algorithm that can solve any Futoshiki puzzle.

Its there any code for this? I have search on google but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A) Stackoverflow is not a site to ask for examples of programs. It is a site to help answer questions about problems with an *existing program*.

B)That said, I can point you to some tutorials.

You didn't find anything? Here are the first 3 results I got from Google:

1. [python-constraint](https://labix.org/python-constraint) is a  module that allows CSP programming. The following is verbatim from their site:

`from constraint import *
    problem = Problem()
    problem.addVariable("a", [1,2,3])
    problem.addVariable("b", [4,5,6])
    problem.getSolutions()
    [{'a': 3, 'b': 6}, {'a': 3, 'b': 5}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4},
     {'a': 2, 'b': 6}, {'a': 2, 'b': 5}, {'a': 2, 'b': 4},
     {'a': 1, 'b': 6}, {'a': 1, 'b': 5}, {'a': 1, 'b': 4}]`

2. [Numberjack](http://numberjack.ucc.ie/) is similar. It seems it is for embeding.

> Numberjack is a modelling package written in Python for constraint programming. Python benefits from a large and active programming community, Numberjack is therefore a perfect tool to embed CP technology into larger applications.
>
> [This](http://agiliq.com/blog/2009/03/constraint-programming-in-python/) is a tutorial for the python-constraints package (number 1).
>
> Finally, [here is a paper about CSPs that talks about Futoshiki problems](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00755794/document).

Good luck.

Comment: If you know the question isn't appropriate for this site, why are you answering it - specifically, why are you answering it in the very manner that we'd want to avoid?

Comment: Because this is a first poster, and while it isn't the point of the site, I like to be helpful, and it doesn't hurt.